# What's the difference between CommandBarEvents.Click and CommandBarButton.Click in VBE?

Tags: vba, events, vb6, vbe, vbide

The **VBA** and **VB6** Add-In Object Models (VBIDE) expose a `CommandBarEvents` object that have a `Click` [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241511(v=vs.60).aspx), and the event signature is:

> ```
> Dim WithEvents CmdBarEvents As CommandBarEvents
>
> Private Sub CmdBarEvents_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, handled As Boolean, CancelDefault As Boolean)
> ```

And a reference to a `CommandBarControl` is passed to `VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents` to register the event handler for that `CommaneBarControl`:

> ```
> Set CmdBarEvents = Application.VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents(CmdBarItem)
> ```

The **Office** object model defines individual CommandBar controls that have their own `Click` [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864867.aspx), for example, the `CommandBarControl` object which has a `Click` event, and the signature is:

> ```
> Dim WithEvents CmdBarBtn As CommandBarButton
>
> Private Sub CmdBarBtn_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
> ```

And a reference to a `CommandBarButton` is assigned to the `WithEvents` object:

> ```
> Set CmdBarButton = myButton
> ```

**Why is there a difference, and which should I prefer?**

I'm attaching events to the controls on the VBE's CommandBars (as opposed to CommandBars within the host application).

Office CommandBars don't have access to a `CommandBarEvents` object, so I assume that they must use the `CommandBarButton.Click` event. But the VBE (under any Office Host) has access to `CommandBarButton` events AND `CommandBarEvents` events, so I *could* use either approach, although the mere presence of the `CommandBarEvents` object suggests that it is the preferred method (and probably the only method in non-Office VBA hosts), and *most* of the online [examples](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VbeMenus.aspx) of adding event handlers to VBE CommandBars *do* use `CommandBarEvents`.

Carlos Quintero of MZ Tools has wonderously useful, but in this case, mildly contradictory information on his site. He suggests that [The CommandBarEvents approach was used in the old Microsoft Visual Basic 5.0 / 6.0 environment](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2011/MZ2011003.aspx), but also uses the `CommandBarControl.Click` approach on this [page](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012015.aspx)

Is there something special about the VBE and attaching events to `CommandBar` controls? Are there any problems (memory leaks, IDTExtensibility2 shutdown problems and the like) if I choose to use the `CommandBarControl` events over the `CommandBarEvents` events?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- VB6, being an IDE from 1998 (and VB5 from 1997) must use always CommandBarEvents. The Office commandbars that they use are borrowed from Office 97, whose CommandBarButton lacked the Click event.
- Office 2000 introduced the Click event in the CommandBarButton class, and must be used always for a VBA add-in targeting Office 2000 and higher (or other VBA hosts), because although CommandBarEvents is apparently available, Office 2010 64-bit doesn't support CommandBarEvents (it crashes if used).
- Visual Studio is another animal with its own singularities.